# Calendar first day of the week fromat in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, sharepoint, calendar

I have an issue with changing calendars first day of the week in IE. It works with JQuery and I have selected for first day of the week to be 1. This calendar is at Sharepoint 2013.

Any ideas, how I could fix this error?

[image: In Internet Explorer 10]

[image: In Google Chrome]

First image is in IE 10 and second one in Google Chrome

Comment: Could you include some of your code in the question please?

Comment: I don't think, this is related that much to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this problem solved, when I cleared all my cache files in IE. Seems like there was some old file, that got triggered instead.